# How to compare two array and get the first matching object from the first array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var arr1 =['Five','Four','Full','Straight','Three','Two','One','Bust']
var arr2 = [{player1-box: "One"},{player2-box: "One"},{player3-box: "Four"},{player1-box: "Three"},{player2-box: "Three"},{player3-box: "Two"},{player1-box: "Five"},{player2-box: "One"},{player3-box: "One"}]
```

I have two array as described above.
My requirement is to compare two arrays and get the first matching value from the second array.
Here in this example value 'FIVE' from arr1 will match the values into the 7th index into the second array arr2

Means I will get the key and value like {player1-box: "Five"} ?
could someone look into this and let me know ?

Thanks..

Comment: Use a for loop or `forEach()`.

Comment: Why that `arr2` ? why not just `{ player1-box: "value", player2-box: "value" }` or `[{ name: "player1", value: "value" }, /*...*/]` ?

Comment: You can't have dashes in the object keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way with the current data setup other than iterating over arr1. This will either return the first found in `arr1` of `undefined` if none are found.

```js
var arr1 =['Five','Four','Full','Straight','Three','Two','One','Bust']
var arr2 = [{'player1-box': "One"},{'player2-box': "One"},{'player3-box': "Four"},{'player1-box': "Three"},{'player2-box': "Three"},{'player3-box': "Two"},{'player1-box': "Five"},{'player2-box': "One"},{'player3-box': "One"}]

function findFirst(keys, players){
    for (key of keys){
        let player = players.find(player => Object.values(player).includes(key))
        if (player) return player
    }
}
let first = findFirst(arr1, arr2)
console.log(first)
```

If there's the possibility of a tie, you could use `filter()` instead of `find()` and return an array:

```js
var arr1 =['Five','Four','Full','Straight','Three','Two','One','Bust']
var arr2 = [{'player1-box': "One"},{'player2-box': "Five"},{'player3-box': "Four"},{'player1-box': "Three"},{'player2-box': "Three"},{'player3-box': "Two"},{'player1-box': "Five"},{'player2-box': "One"},{'player3-box': "One"}]

function findFirst(keys, players){
    for (key of keys){
        let player = players.filter(player => Object.values(player).includes(key))
        if (player) return player
    }
}
console.log(findFirst(arr1, arr2))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate `arr1` with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and exit the loop if an object is found in `arr2` with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

While the objects have different keys, you need to get the values for checking.

```js
var arr1 = ['Five', 'Four', 'Full', 'Straight', 'Three', 'Two', 'One', 'Bust'],
    arr2 = [{ "player1-box": "One" }, { "player2-box": "One" }, { "player3-box": "Four" }, { "player1-box": "Three" }, { "player2-box": "Three" }, { "player3-box": "Two" }, { "player1-box": "Five" }, { "player2-box": "One" }, { "player3-box": "One" }],
    result;

arr1.some(v => result = arr2.find(o => Object.values(o).includes(v)));
console.log(result);
```

Without [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and ES6 parts.

```js
var arr1 = ['Five', 'Four', 'Full', 'Straight', 'Three', 'Two', 'One', 'Bust'],
    arr2 = [{ "player1-box": "One" }, { "player2-box": "One" }, { "player3-box": "Four" }, { "player1-box": "Three" }, { "player2-box": "Three" }, { "player3-box": "Two" }, { "player1-box": "Five" }, { "player2-box": "One" }, { "player3-box": "One" }],
    result;

arr1.some(function (v) {
    return arr2.some(function (o)  {
        if (Object.keys(o).some(function (k) { return v === o[k]; })) {
            return result = o;
        }
    });
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please send it without arrow operator ?